# Console has no method 'debug' in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, console

The `console.debug()` function can be invoked in the browser console.

However there is one error when `console.debug()` is called in Nodejs.

```
TypeError: Object #<Console> has no method 'debug'
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\share\node\receive.js:20:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:929:3
```

Why? Is there any way to replace `console.debug` in Nodejs?

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/console.html

Comment: pls add the relevant node versions to this question, as the behaviour has changed, more than once, on more recent versions

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's no console.debug() method in NodeJS. [Here](http://nodejs.org/api/console.html) is the documentation for the console object, so you can choose the best method for you to use.

Comment: Note that `console.debug()` is present in Node v8 (and possibly v7), but it appears to be a no-op: the function invokes without error, but no content comes out on stdout or stderr.

Comment: Damn, that broke my library.

Comment: [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#consoledebugdata-args): *v8.10.0 console.debug is now an alias for console.log.*

Answer (score 6):

As the previous answer states there is no console.debug() method in node.js. use log,info,warn,error methods https://nodejs.org/api/console.html

That said you might what to extend the console object to include a console.debug() method and only have this method print console messages when in a debug mode.

```
var isDebugMode = true;

console.debug = function(args)
{
  if (isDebugMode){
    console.log(args);
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that `info` is just an alias for `log`, and `warn` is just an alias for `error`. Unlike what the names imply, in Node you cannot set various levels of logging.

Answer (score 5):

## Since node [9.3.0](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V9.md#9.3.0) console.debug will now show by default in stdout.

---

#### Old solution:

`console.debug()` was added in node v8.0.0, but will not normally print to stdout.

You can view console.debug messages by using the `--inspect` or `--inspect-brk` command line flags and enabling verbose logging with the "levels" dropdown in devtools' console tab.

[image: devtools' console tab with default filtering]
[image: devtools' console tab with no filtering]

Unfortunately this does not unsquelch `console.debug`'s output to stdout.

[image: stdout in repl]

As of node v9.2.0 i'm unaware of any way to view `console.debug`'s output in stdout short of replacing the function with a console.log wrapper.

Answer (score 4):

Adding on to @maninvan answer, I'd use variables args syntax:

```
var isDebugMode = true;

console.debug = function(/* ...args */) {
    if(isDebugMode) {
        var vargs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        console.log.apply(this, vargs);
    }
}

// or ES6 style
console.debug = (...args) => {
    if(isDebugMode) {
        console.log.apply(this, args)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#consoledebugdata-args) history says:

> v8.10.0 console.debug is now an alias for console.log

While it's easy to overwrite it with your own function, I prefer to extend `console` and use my own `debug` method, like in this example:

```
xconsole = Object.create(console);

xconsole.debug = function (...line) {
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
                console.log(...line);
        }
}
```

This leaves `console.debug` untouched. I have this in its own file which I [import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41607352/only-require-specific-exports-from-a-required-commonjs-module) to use in other modules. And I can use the new function instead, like this:

```
xconsole.debug("This will only show if NODE_ENV is set to development");
xconsole.log("This will always show");
```

Many variations are possible, of course. See [info](https://nodejs.dev/learn/nodejs-the-difference-between-development-and-production) on `NODE_ENV`.

I use this approach to conveniently enable debug mode on docker containers. I have an alias on my `~/.bashrc` to [propagate the environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables) since I need to run docker with `sudo`:

```
alias docker='sudo -E docker'
```

And if I need to enable debug mode it's as simple as `export NODE_ENV=development`. Testing:

```
docker run --name test -d -e NODE_ENV node:17-bullseye env
```

I can see `NODE_ENV=development` with `docker logs test`. It's good to be mindful of security when [exporting environment variables to root](https://askubuntu.com/a/161930/628938) (`-E`), but this is fine for my development environment.

Answer (score 0):

With node 8.10.0 and above support has been added for console.debug()

https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/162ff56439